# Pythonでスマートに辞書型の中に配列を定義する方法

Tags: python

以下のように、Pythonで辞書型を使って"time"というキーに対して、現在時間の配列を持たせるコードを書きました。

**test.py**

```
import time
mydict = {}
timeList = []
for i in range(3):
    timeList.append(time.time())
    mydict["time"] = timeList
print(mydict)
```

**test.pyの出力結果**は以下のようになります。

```
{'time': [1583738314.135982, 1583738314.135982, 1583738314.135982]}
```

これは私が求めている通りの出力結果なのですが
出来れば3行目の`timeList = []`をfor文の外で定義したくありません。

なぜなら、test2.pyのように辞書の中身を増やしたい場合に
どんどんプログラムの行数が増えていってしまうからです。

**test2.py**

```
import time
mydict = {}
timeList = []#現在の値のリスト
time10secList = []#10sec後の値のリスト
time20secList = []#20sec後の値のリスト
for i in range(3):
    timeList.append(time.time())
    mydict["time"] = timeList

    time10secList.append(time.time()+10)
    mydict["time10sec"] = time10secList

    time20secList.append(time.time()+20)
    mydict["time20sec"] = time20secList
print(mydict)
```

**test2.pyの出力結果**

```
{
'time': [1583738637.765196, 1583738637.765196, 1583738637.765196], 
'time10sec': [1583738647.765196, 1583738647.765196, 1583738647.765196],
 'time20sec': [1583738657.765196, 1583738657.765196, 1583738657.765196]
}
```

理想としては、test3.pyのような形で、短くまとめたいのですが、以下のコードだとエラーになってしまいます。

**test3.py**

```
import time
mydict = {}
for i in range(3):
    mydict["time"].append(time.time())
    mydict["time10sec"].append(time.time()+10)
    mydict["time20sec"].append(time.time()+20)
print(mydict)
```

どうしたらスマートに辞書型を定義し、配列を更新していけますか？

Comment: List comprehension を使って `for delta in (0, 10, 20): mydict[f'time{delta}sec' if delta else 'time'] = [time.time()+delta for _ in range(3)]` の様にもできます(スマートかどうかは分かりませんけれども)。

Comment: test2.pyの出力結果が信じがたい(そんなマシン実在する? という感じな)のですけれど、「やること」としてソースの方を信じればいいですか? 「やりたい理想」として出力結果の方を信じればいいですか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collections.defaultdict`を使うと以下のように書けます。

```py
import time
import collections
mydict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in range(3):
    mydict["time"].append(time.time())
    mydict["time10sec"].append(time.time()+10)
    mydict["time20sec"].append(time.time()+20)
print(mydict)
```

Answer (score 3):

`mydict = {}`の代りに`mydict = {'time':[],'time10sec':[],'time20sec':[]}`では駄目なのでしょうか？
こんな風に。

```
import time
mydict = {'time':[],'time10sec':[],'time20sec':[]}
for i in range(3):
    mydict["time"].append(time.time())
    mydict["time10sec"].append(time.time()+10)
    mydict["time20sec"].append(time.time()+20)
print(mydict)
```

Answer (score 1):

内包表記で

```py
from itertools import repeat
import time

t = time.time()
mydict = {k: [t + p] * 3
          for k, p in [["time", 0], ["time10sec", 10], ["time20sec", 20]]}
```

とか。

普通のループだと

```py
mydict = {}
t = time.time()
for k, p in [["time", 0], ["time10sec", 10], ["time20sec", 20]]:
    mydict.setdefault(k, []).extend([t + p] * 3)
```

とか。

---

コードと結果が合致してないように見えるので正解がわかりませんが、それは追記していただくとして、ひとまず。

---

正直なところスマートに書く方法なんてたくさんあるのですけれど、スマートさよりも**ずっと大事**なのは、どの部分が「将来変更される可能性が高い」か「将来にわたって不変である可能性が高い」かだと思いました。
それで方針が変わるだろう、と。